# The conditional distribution of Gaussian random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability

A random variable $h$ is defined as Gaussian distributed with mean $N$ and variance $N$. In the case of $N \rightarrow \infty$, it's easy to show that for any $u$,
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} P(h>u)=1$$
First question is that can we conclude that $h$ approaches to infinity with complete certainty?

Under that condition that $N \rightarrow \infty$,
$P(h)$ shares the same distribution with $P(h|h\rightarrow \infty)$

Is this statement true or false?

Comment: "$h$ approaches to infinity with complete certainty?"  That statement doesn't mean anything, unless you give some definition. Likewise, you ned to define what the condition " $|h \to \infty$ means

Comment: I suspect that $P(h|h\rightarrow \infty)$ means that $P(\lim_{N \to \infty} h_N>u)=1$

Comment: Still interested in an answer?